# Dockerfile Alpine Mariadb latest with SphinxSE

Tags: docker, mariadb, alpine-package-keeper

I have a Dockerfile for MariaDB `10.1.26` which I use in connection with `SphixSE`.

Defining Dockerfiles for versions `10.4.18` and `10.5.9` along the same lines is easy, but SphinxSE cannot be installed.

Specifically the command `INSTALL SONAME 'ha_sphinx';` raises an enigmatic error.

What can I do to make it work with these versions, too?

Comment: The packages I am looking for seem to appear in above URL under `Sub Packages`. Nevertheless, they seem to be not implemented somehow. You can verify at docker hub `kklepper/mariadb33-v10.5.9`

Answer (score 0):

For the time being it cannot be done.

https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/mariadb/APKBUILD#n162 shows that the package does not support `SphinxSE`.

https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/pull/343 shows that `MariaDB` does not support `Alpine`.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Your answers does not meet community standards. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer